# Cannot upload svg logo prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I want to upload an SVG logo in prestashop 1.6 but my logo is automatically transformed to jpeg i tried to customize validateUpload in ImageManager class to accept svg extension, i did it, now svg are uploaded but after that they are transformed to jpeg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your database, in configuration table change value as logo.svg where name equal PS_LOGO. this is the sql query to execute on your dbb server :

```
UPDATE ps_configuration SET value='logo.svg' WHERE name = 'PS_LOGO';
```

By default the value is logo.jpg

Comment: Thanks a lot that's very helpful, but my problem now is that i figure out that svg file is not uploaded i did not find my image in /img directory so i want to find the function wich upload the logo to cutomize it, i try to check the AdminThemesController  but i didn't find the function wich upload the logo.

Comment: What are your modification in adminthemecontroller ? i supposed in the function updateLogo()

Comment: Thanks, that's it, i guess this is the function wich i look for.

Comment: Thanks a lot i appreciate that, i moved the image manually and it work, it's not the best solution but it work for the moment.

Comment: don't forget to embed the width and height in the svg otherwise you'll be greeted with a brobdingnagian logo, depending on where it's being used, starring you in the face :))